# Installing Hyper-V Role on Server 2012 R2 Without the Hypervisor

Tags: virtualization, windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v-server-2012-r2, hypervisor

I have a Windows 2012 R2 Essentials Server running on top of Hyper-V Server 2012 R2.

In server manager on the Essentials Server, I'd like to be able to manage other Hyper-V servers remotely. I'm unable to install this role because I'm already running in a VM.

Is there a way to install the Hyper-V Management Tools without the system attempting (and failing) to install the actual hypervisor?

Comment: Ah, yes? Like they have separate entries in the windows feature installation dialog. You can install any RSAT (Remote Server Administration Tool) component. What did you try?

Comment: Server Manager -> Add Roles and Features -> Role Based -> [Select Server] ->  Hyper-V -> Check "Include Management Tools" ->Add Features. The error is "A hypervisor is already running". There is no option using this method to install the management tools without the hypervisor that I can see.

Comment: Server Manager -> Add Roles and Features -> Role Based -> (do not add role) -> FEATURES -> Remote Server Administratoin Tools -> Role Administration Tools -> Hyper-V Management Tools. You want the RSAT tools, not the Hyper-V role.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, you can do this. You have two options:

1. Open PowerShell and run following command that will install only the Hyper-V Manager and it's dependencies:

   `Add-Windowsfeature rsat-hyper-v-tools`
2. Download and install RSAT (Remote Server Administration Tools) [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2693643/remote-server-administration-tools-rsat-for-windows-operating-systems) that will provide you with all the server management tools including Server Manager, Hyper-V Manager and so on.